# Unable to copy and paste from machine to Virtual Machine (Hyper-V) and back

Tags: copy-paste, hyper-v

I am using VM (Hyper-V) and I simply want to copy and paste files, text, etc. directly from my machine (Windows 10) to the VM. How can I do this without using Remote Desktop Connection, TeamViewer, etc.?

Comment: it's was working in my case and suddenly stopped solution was switching to basic than turn the hyper v Enhanced Session Mode again

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in Hyper-V Post windows server 2012 R2.

This functionality is known as **"Enhanced Session Mode"** in windows server 2012 R2.

Once you enable Enhance session mode in the Hyper-V setting for the Server you need to just start the VM and select **"Connect"** once prompted.

Now you will be able to copy paste files and folders without having RDP of the server.

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: Is it also possible in Windows 10?

Comment: Today I was unable to paste but disabling "Enhanced Session Mode" in the menu at the top added a "Clipboard" menu item that types the characters into the VM guest. So, if you having trouble with enhanced session mode and you need to paste text input, try disabling it temporarily.

Comment: This does not seem to work and even if it did I believe this only works in the host -> guest direction right?

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is only good if your guest is Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Debain 9.9 as my HyperV VM on my work computer.  Using the "Files" utility (linux's version of File Explorer) I clicked on "Other Locations" and entered "smb://ipaddress/C$" and could then browse my "shared" C: drive.  I could also use my computer's name in place of its IP address.  And of course by C: drive was already a shared resource in Windows.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Home edition of Windows for the VM. You have to have Windows Pro installed in order to copy paste files.